# Recurrence Relations

Tags: recurrence-relations

```
        Base Case: T(1) = 0;        


        T(n) = 1 + T(N/2)

        plug = 1 + 1(1 + T(N/4))

        chug = 2 + T(N/4)

        plug = 2 + 1 (1 + T(N/8))

        chug = 3 + T(N/8)

        plug = 3 + 1 (1 + T(N/16))

        chug = 4 + T(N/16)

        pattern = i + T(N/2^i)


        N/2^i = 1

        2^i = N

        i = log_2(N)

        final equation : 

        log_(2)N + T(1)


        Conlusion : O(log_N)
```

I have tried solving the question, but I'm not sure whether the method i used was correct. Plz review.

Comment: You are trying to give an answer. What question does this attempt to answer

Comment: What is the conclusion?  The computational complexity?

Comment: Yes the computational complexity, is the solution correct?

Comment: I'm actually solving the recurrence, the questions was
solve the recurrenc T(N)= T(N/2) + 1

Comment: Your work is sort of correct.  But the "pattern" step is just a guess.  You need to actually prove that the guess is correct.  I suggest inductively establishing that $T(n) = \log_2(n)$.